# Taking both sides of an issue for personal gain

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or two for a person who would support or defend either side of an issue for personal gain. In other words, a person who is not interested in truth for truth's sake but for personal gain or advantage.

Comment: There are a half-dozen different idioms:  Working both sides of the street.  Double-dealing.  Being "two-faced".

Comment: There's the Vicar of Bray. And *trimmer* - I haven't heard it for a while, but it was certainly in use from the Restoration into the 1970s.

Comment: I think they call them lawyers :-)

Comment: He ***runs with the hare and hunts with the hounds***.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like ***[mercenary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mercenary),*** adjective or noun: "working or acting merely for money or other reward; venal."